# Склонение числительного

Tags: числительные

Как правильно склонять числительное 4575 в творительном падеже?

Answer (score 2):

Это просто: *четырьмя тысячами семьюдесятью пятью.* См. раздел «Числительное» в любом школьном учебнике русского языка. :)

Answer (score 1):

Четырьмя тысячами *пятьюстами* семьюдесятью пятью.

Comment: Верно. Пропустил сотни.

Answer (score 0):

Cклонение - это изменение по падежам. Нельзя  склонять в каком-то одном падеже. Поэтому данный вопрос грамотно звучал бы в таком варианте: как правильно **употребить**  числительное 4575 в творительном падеже.

Comment: Творительный падеж - это ещё что. Однажды спросили "Как склоняется счет-фактура в прошедшем времени?"

Comment: Ну точно не так, как в настоящем или в будущем...